# I separated backend and frontend into 2 different projects but I can't use breakpoints in the frontend one

Tags: .net-core, breakpoints

I'm working on a project and we needed to separate backend and frontend into two projects. And while working on it I was getting some frontend errors, I tried to set breakpoints to find the issue but the breakpoints aren't working because the project is started from the command prompt, I suppose. Does anyone know how I can set breakpoints in the frontend project?

Comment: So I understood you this way: you have a solution which has two projects, backend and frontend. You start one of your projects from command line and another one in debug mode from Visual Studio. Break points in the one from the command line don't work. Did I get you right?

Comment: I have the backend as an API, and the frontend is opened as a folder, both in VS, but the frontend is run through cmd. In the API project(the backend part) I can set breakpoints normally, but because the frontend is not run through VS but cmd, I can't set any breakpoints to debug my project and see where the error is coming from. I can use Console.log() but it's not helping me as of right now that's why I posted this.

Comment: Why is the front end project run as cmd? Would it possible to set up multiple startup projects? (solution properties -> startup projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your project is not running by (on-watch) for axample "nodemon" or "--watch" command

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new in the programming world. Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: How do I do that?